# runBlocking does not wait for everything

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, kotlin-coroutines, android-testing

I have a list screen with items in a recyclerview, the items comes from a database and is observed via a livedata values from a viewmodel.
But when I try to create a instrumented test the test fails to find the inserted items in the recyclerview. If I look at the device I can see the item come into view when the test fails.

I think it checks the screen for the view and just a moment after it comes into view and that's why I can see it. But why does `runBlocking()` not manage to block everything? If I add a delay after inserting into the repository the test completes. Sometimes the test also complete without a delay.

Error

```
androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Some crazy text."
```

Fragment `onCreateView()`

```kotlin
viewModel.messages.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    //show all messages
    adapter.setMessages(it)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
})
```

ViewModel

```kotlin
val messages: LiveData<List<Message>> = messagesRepository.observeMessages()
```

Adapter

```kotlin
fun setMessages(newList: List<Message>){
    this.list = newList
    selectionList = MutableList(list.size) { false }
}
```

Test code

```kotlin
@Test
fun editMessage() = runBlocking {
    val message = Message(message = "Some crazy text.")

    val id = repository.insert(message)

    //navigate to detail fragment
    onView(withText(message.message)).perform(click())
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that working with adapters needs usage of `onData` not `onView`

Comment: Is this espresso? If is so then you have to use https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource